# about Epi-convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, optimization

I have a question about epi-converge as defined in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epi-convergence.
where $\liminf_{v \to \infty}f^v(x^v)\geq f(x)$ and
$\limsup_{v \to \infty}f^v(x^v)\leq f(x)$
But $\inf\{\} ≤ \sup\{\}$, how can the above set of inequality stand?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You did not reproduce the full definition.
$$
\liminf_{v \to \infty}f^v(x^v)\geq f(x)
$$
has to hold for **every** sequence $x^v$ while
$$
\limsup_{v \to \infty}f^v(x^v)\leq f(x)
$$
has to hold for **at least one** sequence. For those sequences where the second condition holds, you have of course in combination that $$\lim_{v \to \infty}f^v(x^v)= f(x).$$